# How to avoid using 'this' pointer in javascript (ES5/ES6)?

Tags: javascript, ember.js, web

According to Crockford, the best practice is NOT using this pointer due to security issues.

I found this in the [Ember guide](http://guides.emberjs.com/v1.11.0/object-model/classes-and-instances/),

```
Person = Ember.Object.extend({
  say: function(thing) {
    var name = this.get('name');
    alert(name + " says: " + thing);
  }
});

Soldier = Person.extend({
  say: function(thing) {
    this._super(thing + ", sir!");
  }
});

var yehuda = Soldier.create({
  name: "Yehuda Katz"
});

yehuda.say("Yes"); // alerts "Yehuda Katz says: Yes, sir!"
```

How can this be avoided in such code situations?

Comment: Where does Crockford say this?  I feel we're lacking some context.

Comment: What security issues does he refer to? If you don't understand the attack vector, it's unlikely that you can avoid issues just by not using `this`.

Comment: If the only source of this advice is a section of video, it can't be very good advice or it would be replicated elsewhere.  JavaScript security is taken very seriously by a lot of people, and the best practices are well documented.

Comment: @RichieHindle He explains it well why it should not be used.

Comment: @kalpa: Maybe you pointed us to the wrong link?

Comment: @mmgross If you put 'this' in a method, this gets bound to the object of interest which is what you want but if you take that method and call it as a function 'this' get bound to the global object which destroys all security.

Comment: @Bergi my apologies it was the wrong link ... right one here https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=PSGEjv3Tqo0

Comment: @mmgross my apologies it was a wrong link

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> the best practice is NOT using this pointer due to security issues.

Not exactly. His argument is that you cannot trust `this` in an unsafe environment, because it is determined by the caller. It's all about encapsulation, and the safety that your methods only do what you want them to do. Methods that do use `this` can possibly be tricked into doing something else.

Consider

```
function Person(name) {
    this.name = name;
    this.say = function(thing) {
        alert(this.name+" says: "+thing);
    };
}
var p = new Person("John");
p.say("this is unsafe");
```

A malicious caller with access to `p` could do

```
p.say.call({name: "Douglas"}, "this is totally safe");
```

(assume he does not have access to `alert`, and assume he doesn't want to simply alter `p.name`)

A safer constructor would be

```
function Person(name) {
    return {
        say: function(thing) {
            alert(this.name+" says: "+thing);
        }
    };
}
```

So when a malicious agent is passed `Person("John")`, then he only can make `John` say something.

> How can this be avoided in such code situations?

Not at all. Ember embraces `this`, it is very useful indeed, and you should use it as you are supposed to by the framework.

Answer (score 2):

In the video you're referring to, Crockford says that using `this` leads to poor security *in the specific case* of implementing a JavaScript sandbox to allow third party code to run safely, for instance for Facebook to allow ads to run their own JavaScript on Facebook's pages without compromising the users' security.  Eliminating `this` from the code is a simple way to prevent code from accessing the `window` object, which is necessary in this sort of sandboxed environment.

He *doesn't* say that `this` leads to poor security in the general case, but *only* in the case of a sandbox.

He does say that since working with such a system he has stopped using `this` in his own code, but he doesn't elaborate on that very much, and again this is not a comment about general JavaScript security.